# Error comparación celdas Excel

Tags: excel, macros, comparaciones, formato-condicional

Buenas tardes a todos!!

He estado trabajando en una macro de Excel que quiero que me haga lo siguiente, me abra dos archivos de Excel, compare que los nombres de las hojas son iguales y luego revise celda a celda si el contenido de las mismas es el mismo y, si no lo es, me lo marque en amarillo.

El problema es que una vez que me lee la primera celda la macro se sale del Excel y solo me compara la primera celda, ¿Cómo puedo hacer que me recorra todas las celdas de todas las hojas y que no se salga del bucle?

Muchas gracias por adelantado!

```
Sub Comparar_Excel()
 
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, wsMatch As Boolean
 
  'Open a file dialog to select workbooks (optional)
ruta_wb1 = Sheets("Hoja comandos").Cells(3, 8)
ruta_wb2 = Sheets("Hoja comandos").Cells(9, 8)
 
nombre_wb1 = Sheets("Hoja comandos").Cells(5, 8)
nombre_wb2 = Sheets("Hoja comandos").Cells(11, 8)
 
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=ruta_wb1, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, Local:=True
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=ruta_wb2, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, Local:=True
 
  'Set each of the 2 workbooks to object variables
Set wb1 = Workbooks(nombre_wb1)
Set wb2 = Workbooks(nombre_wb2)
 
If wb1.Worksheets.Count = wb2.Worksheets.Count Then
 
    'Loop through worksheets
    For Each ws1 In wb1.Worksheets
      wsMatch = False
      For Each ws2 In wb2.Worksheets
        If ws1.Name = ws2.Name Then
          wsMatch = True
          'Compare the 2 worksheets
          For Each cell In ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            If cell.Value <> ws2.Range(cell.Address).Value Then
                cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
'                MsgBox "Mismatch cell " & cell.Address & " in worksheet " & ws1.Name
            End If
          Next cell
        End If
      Next ws2
      If wsMatch = False Then ws1.Tab.Color = vbYellow
    Next ws1
Else
    MsgBox "Worksheets mismatch"
End If
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Comprueba que `ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion` esté cogiendo más de 1 celda

Comment: Tengo claro que el error está en esa línea de código, por que solo pilla esa celda y se sale del bucle, pero no se entiendo por que no sigue recorriendo las celdas de la matriz que he generado.

Comment: `CurrentRegion` selecciona la región entera de celdas **siempre y cuando** Excel reconozca dicha región. Si alguna parte de tus datos está separada por una fila/columna entera en blanco, eso inicia una nueva región. ¿Qué obtienes si haces `ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Cells.Count`? ¿Cómo tienes los datos en Excel puestos?